# cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'list' cannot have character

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have tried the solutions present on the other question which looks similar , but I was not able to get it.
I am configuring the spring dispatcher servlet .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">



    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/views.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.controller" />


</beans>
```

However , it always throws the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 18 in XML document from ServletContext resou
rce [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18;
 columnNumber: 20; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'list' cannot have character [children], because the type's content typ
e is element-only.
```

I have question here , when it comes to schema version would it be same which we have specified in the pom.xml file, I have the following elements in the pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <!-- <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>  -->
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Springs Element 'beans' cannot have character \[children\], because the type's content type is element-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725306/springs-element-beans-cannot-have-character-children-because-the-types-con)

Comment: @Tunaki : Not a duplicate

Comment: Spring version mentioned in pom.xml is 4.1.1.RELEASE, where as  schema mentioned in app context file is spring-beans-2.5.xsd. Please make it consistent and hopefully it will solve the issue.

Comment: changed it from 2.5.xsd to 4.1.xsd , still it gives the same error

Comment: Ideally you should go with version less schema, so that you dont have to change it evey time you change your version. Schema is shipped with jars so you can totally remove the version. check this thread for more info
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue one day, I think the main cause of this error is the use of a key word or an expression that's not excpected. for example:

The framework expects this :

```
<list>
<value>VALUE_EXPRESSION</value>
</list>
```

but you do this :

```
<list>
<value>VALUE_EXPRESSION</value>sss
</list>
```

> The ***sss*** after is illegal, it is not expected.

Or, any other thing that breaks the main rule described in its xsd file.

Hope this helps.